rebuild child's viewModel once parent viewModel call for a rebuildUi
description:
I have a parent widget where its view Model feed child’s view with values.
At first creation the values arrive from parent’s view model to the child’s view model via the child's view as it has been called on parent's view, but once I rebuildUi in parent’s view model, the change arrives to the child’s view but not to it’s view model, I know that it is because child’s viewModel's lifecycle it is created,
but I think there is a solution for that ?
stacked don't provide any solutions for that ?
I don't want to use Services (injection btw viewModel's)
I don't want to use Notifier's
I don't want to use
